# No se ejecuta correctamente google apps script

Tags: trigger, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un Google Apps Script como función `onEdit()` que cuando se modifica la columna H a "DESISTIDA" o a "FORMALIZADA" debería ocultar la fila donde figurará alguno de esos dos códigos.

Posteriormente debe mandar todas las filas y columnas de la hoja (llamada BD1) a otro hoja de cálculo(que se encuentra cerrada) y al final mostrará un mensaje de modificación realizada.

Encuentro los siguientes problemas:

1. Cuando se edita la celda no se ejecuta inmediatamente el script (tarda muchísimo cuando por fin se ejecuta)
2. No oculta la fila
3. Aparece el mensaje antes de ocultar la fila si la oculta.

Llevo varios días intentando solucionarlo pero no hago nada más que estropear la función.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

La función es esta:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('       ');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('BD1'); 

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      for( i=1 ; i <= lastRow ; i++) { //i <== lastRow
            var Aviso = sheet.getRange ("J1"). getValues();
            var status = sheet.getRange ("P" + i). getValues(); 
            if (status == "DESISTIDA") {   


                var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

                var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

                var SData = SRange.getValues();

                var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('   '); 
                var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Hoja 1'); 
                    ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
                   sheet.hideRows(i);
                 }

            if (status == "FORMALIZADA") {


                var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

                var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

                var SData = SRange.getValues();

                var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('     '); 
                var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Hoja 1'); 

                 ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
                   sheet.hideRows(i);
                 }


      }
    Browser.msgBox("Se ha modificado el identificador " + Aviso);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Encuentro los siguientes problemas:
>
> 1. Cuando se edita la celda no se ejecuta inmediatamente el script (tarda muchísimo cuando por fin se ejecuta)

El script es ineficiente. Para mejorar su desempeño, reduce las llamadas a servicios de Google Apps Script, por ejemplo, usa el objeto evento

- cambia `function onEdit()` por `function onEdit(e)` (el nombre del argumento puede ser el que tu quieras, generalmente se usa `e` por la inicial de "event"). Luego puedes obtener el rango que ha sido editado con `e.range`.
- estas reusando la misma variable inmediatamente, esto sólo consume tiempo. Me refiero a

```
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('BD1'); 

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

No tiene sentido usar `openById` pues los activadores simples como `onEdit` se ejecutan con permisos limitados.

- Existen varios reportes de que getLastRow() en ocasiones es muy lento. En su lugar puedes intentar con `sheet.getDataRange().getValues().length` donde `sheet` es un objeto Sheet del cual quieres obtener su última fila con datos.

El tiempo de recálculo de la hoja afecta el desempeño aparente de `onEdit`. Quizás debas revisar las fórmulas para reducir el tiempo de recálculo y así mejorar el desempeño aparente de `onEdit`

> 2. No oculta la fila

Dado que el objeto evento incluye el rango que ha sido editado, puedes cambiar radicalmente la lógica y resolver esto, por ejemplo, dado que `e.range` te devuelve el rango editado ya no tienes que iterar sobre todas las filas. Para obtener la fila usa `e.range.getRow()`

> 3. Aparece el mensaje antes de ocultar la fila si la oculta.

Esto usualmente se resuelve incluyendo `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` antes de llamar diálogos.

Cabe destacar que el uso de Browser no lo recomienda el propio Google. En su lugar usa `SpreadsheetApp.getUI().alert(mensaje)`

Comment: Muchas gracias. Voy a corregirlo.

Comment: @JCarlos Si no lo has hecho aún, por favor revisa [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)